# Moved from Blogger to Wordpress, need to rewrite some URLs

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, blogger

I just recently moved from Blogger to Wordpress.

Blogger's archive URLs were something like this: `/2013_08_01_archive.html`

I need to rewrite that to `/2013/8`, I'm assuming in .htaccess. I need to do it where it will work for all past archive links to 2010 or so. Is there a way to make this rewrite work for anything with that pattern?

For example:

```
/2014_11_01_archive.html -> /2014/11
/2013_10_01_archive.html -> /2013/10
/2009_01_01_archive.html -> /2009/1
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(\d{4})_0?(\d{1,2})_\d{2}_archive\.html$ /$1/$2 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: It's close, this worked `/2013_10_archive.html` and redirected to `/2013/10` but the pattern is `/2013_10_01_archive.html`.